# UISegmentedControl does not detect segment change in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl

```
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]autorelease];
    bottomSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
    [bottomSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"messages.png"] atIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [bottomSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"news.png"] atIndex:1 animated:YES];
    [bottomSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chart.png"] atIndex:2 animated:YES];
    //bottomSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Messages",@"News",@"Chart", nil]];
    //bottomSegmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [bottomSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    bottomSegmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    bottomSegmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,30);
    bottomSegmentedControl.momentary = NO;
    [bottomSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    UIBarButtonItem *segButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bottomSegmentedControl];
```

When I step through the program `[bottomSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];` does not trigger a UIControlEventValueChanged event which is where I do some stuff in `segmentedControlChanged:`

This used to work in iOS 4.3 but not in iOS5. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I thought UIControlEvenValueChanged only gets called when the user actually pressing a different segment not by a coding change. Anyway why can't you just call the method you want to be fired when you change the 'setSelectedSegmentIndex'?

Comment: I need to swap images in and out when the segmentedControl changes. I assumed my addTarget: would pick this up. Do I have the wrong controlEvent?

Comment: No, like @Caleb said, it is most likely a bug since I remember doing this back in iOS 4 and it worked then.

Comment: Is there an alternative route I can take?

Comment: Depends, not sure what code is in your segmentedControlChanged:

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISegmentedControl change event not firing in iOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054728/uisegmentedcontrol-change-event-not-firing-in-ios5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](http://openradar.appspot.com/9695171). It's not clear whether Apple considers the new behavior to be a feature or a bug.

Comment: Is there an alternative route I can take?

Comment: If you're calling `-setSelectedSegmentIndex:`, you already know that the selected index has changed, so you can do whatever you'd do in response to UIControlEventValueChanged.

Comment: It is clear that apple considers this as a feature and is intensionally done to adjust the UISegmentedControl towards the behavior of other UIControl's.

Answer (score 5):

This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054774/883413

In iOS5 the events from a UISegmentedControl are no longer fired if the value is changed programatically, to keep consistency with the behaviour of other UIControls.

A quick solution is to add:

```
[bottomSegmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

after

```
[bottomSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

however it will call your selector

```
segmentedControlChanged:
```

twice in iOS<5

Comment: You can always detect which iOS, then send it or not.