# UISegmentedControl change event not firing in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl whose "Value changed" event is wired up in Interface Builder to call my controller's `-(IBAction)segmentChangeAction:(id)sender;`

When the user taps on the control to change the selected segment, as expected `segmentChangeAction` is called whether in iOS4 or iOS5.

When I programmatically change the selected segment through `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = newIndex;`, on iOS4 `segmentChangeAction` is called and the segment reflects the new selection. However on iOS5 `segmentChangeAction` is *not* called, yet the segment does reflect the new selection.

Is this a change in iOS5? Is there anything I can do to get `segmentChangeAction` called on iOS5 when I programmatically change the selection?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is a change in iOS 5 in order for `UISegmentedControl` to be consistent with all other controls.

The idea is that the action should only fired automatically as a result of user interaction.  Prior to iOS 5, `UISegmentedControl`'s actions would be fired because of user interaction *and* programmatic interaction.  However, initiating the change programmatically means that you can also do `[myControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]` yourself.

However, you have to be careful with this.  Say you do:

```
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:newIndex];
[segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

If you build and run this on iOS 5, it works as you expect.  If you build and run this on iOS 4, you'll get your actions fired *twice* (once when you `setSelectedSegmentIndex` and again when you `sendActions...`).

The way around this is to do some sort of guard.  This could be a runtime check to indicate that you're running on an iOS 5+ device, or could even be something more mundane, like this:

```
// changingIndex is a BOOL ivar
changingIndex = YES;
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:newIndex];
changingIndex = NO;
[segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and then in your action method...

```
- (void)segmentedControlSelectedIndexChanged:(id)sender {
  if (!changingIndex) {
    // your action code here, guaranteed to only run as a result of the sendActions... msg
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation! I've done the simplest thing (calling `segmentChangeAction` directly after changing the index), having verified that there is no issue with this code being called twice on iOS<5. But I feel much happier knowing why I had to do this, thank you.

Comment: @Vin not this year; I'm way too busy to give it the attention being a moderator deserves.

Comment: @Clafou you're welcome! And if you find a `UIControl` that does *not* follow this behavior, please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) and it'll get fixed. :)

Comment: @Dave that's bad...looks like this year too we won't have anyone from iOS or objective c :(

Comment: @Vin Brad Larson, BoltClock, and Moshe have been nominated and are all active in the Cocoa-related tags.

Comment: @Dave Thanks...I will go through their nominations.

Comment: Why is this not mentioned in the documentation? In fact, it still specifically states 

> When the user touches a segment to change the selection, the control event UIControlEventValueChanged is generated; if the segmented control is set up to respond to this control event, it sends a action message to its target.

Comment: @FelipeSalazar that's still the case. The `UIControlEventValueChanged` event used to be generated from user interaction and programmatic interaction.  Now it is only generated from user interaction (which is consistent with all other built-in controls).

Comment: By the way, there is a cleaner way to detect iOS version: BOOL atLeastIOS5_0 = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0;

Answer (score 5):

I found another way, probably bit easier to understand
you can extend UISegmentedControl and add target action in init methods and call a delegate method to trigger the value change

here is the example code

header file looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class CGUISegmentedControl;

@protocol CGUISegmentedControlDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void) segmentedControl:(CGUISegmentedControl *) control valueChangedTo:(NSInteger) nValue;

@end

@interface CGUISegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl

@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id <CGUISegmentedControlDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

---

.m file

```
    #import "CGUISegmentedControl.h"

@implementation CGUISegmentedControl

@synthesize delegate                = _delegateAction;

- (void) addTargetAction {

    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(indexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addTargetAction];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self addTargetAction];
    }
    return self;

}

- (id) initWithItems:(NSArray *)items {

    self = [super initWithItems:items];
   if (self) {
        [self addTargetAction];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self addTargetAction];
    }
    return self;

}

- (void) indexChanged:(id) sender {

    if (_delegateAction && [_delegateAction respondsToSelector:@selector(segmentedControl:valueChangedTo:)])
        [_delegateAction segmentedControl:self valueChangedTo:self.selectedSegmentIndex];


}

@end
```

---

And you can set the delegate in the calling class