# UISegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, ios-simulator

I have a weird problem with UISegmentedControl.
I'm setting the selected segment index by using the method:

```
[self.toolbarSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

So the problem is - the click handler:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlClick:(id)sender
```

is not called in simulator but under device it IS called when passing this method. Why so and where is the wrong and right behavoir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the iOS version on your device is different to that of your simulator.
The behaviour of `setSelectedSegmentIndex` has changed in iOS5 -- specifically, `segmentChangeAction` is no longer called as a result. See [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054728/uisegmentedcontrol-change-event-not-firing-in-ios5) for details.

Answer (score 6):

Your handler is intercepting the event `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

When you change a value of a `UIControl` programmatically, you should not count on that this event will be invoked, because only user interactions should send actions of UIControl.

Instead, if you wish, you can invoke it yourself:

```
[self.toolbarSegmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[self.toolbarSegmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

That will do it.

Comment: The point is that I'm NOT counting on that the event is invoked! Further more the event must not be called (e.g setting a UISlider's value doesn't emit a Value Changed event. Setting a UISwitch's on doesn't emit a Value Changed event and so on) and furthermore it is a reported apple bug ID# 8372405!

Comment: Even so - it worked for what I needed - which was what you thought, Avraham. Thanks.