# ios5 programmatically setting setSelectedSegmentIndex not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uisegmentedcontrol

I've read [UISegmentedControl change event not firing in iOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054728/uisegmentedcontrol-change-event-not-firing-in-ios5)
Double checked, triple checked, still can't figure it out

```
.h

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <PSStackedViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;    
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged: (id) sender;


.m
@synthesize segmentedControl;
```

In viewDidLoad

```
UIView *containerHeaderView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 60)] autorelease];

NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Favoutites", @"All stories", nil];
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];


segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake( 85.0, 10.0, 300.0, 30.0);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
[segmentedControl setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.80 green:0.80 blue:0.80 alpha:1.0]];

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

[containerHeaderView addSubview:segmentedControl];

// Add header to table
_tableView.tableHeaderView = containerHeaderView;
```

Then later one in the same .m

```
    // select the first segment
    NSLog(@"Switching to News %d",segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
    // iOS4 style
    //self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

    //iOS5 style

    [self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    [segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
    [self.segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSLog(@"After Switch %d",segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
```

Prints out...

```
Switching to News 0
After Switch 0
```

... the segments don't change colour, the index doesn't change.

There's no xib

Clicking the uisegmentcontrol works fine though, just wont change programatically. Although setting the index during it's creation does work.

Why wont setSelectedSegmentIndex ??????

TIA

UPDATE:

It seems the problem lies with using the PSStackedViewDelegate which was causes the view to be created twice....

Comment: Try getting rid of the Ivar. It's not needed. Then change the references to self.segmentedControl.

Comment: I put together a quick demo based on your code, couldn't reproduce the problem. See if this works for you, and if it does, figure out what the difference is between this and your code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11290499/segment.zip (Tip: make sure all your outlets are connected!)

Comment: @davehayden - I've now got the index switching but no visual updating. I spent an hour or so playing with where I created the UIView. I think the culprit in this lies in my use of PSStackedViewDelegate - there is a weird anomaly that when a view is created from say viewDidLoad rather than didSelectRowAtIndexPath the  view was created twice in very quick succession - which I'm guessing caused the issue. The code is now working if not the visual side of it. I can live with this for now. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @JulianB Where is your segmented control being displayed? Is it in a toolbar?

Comment: @Computer No in a tableHeaderCell but after much digging it turned out that the PSStackedViewDelegate was causing this strange voodoo, I'm not sure how but there were other issues with the view being created twice, and once I had solved those the segmentControl behaved.